# When to go for @Configuration and @Component in a spring application?

Tags: spring

We all know that both these annotations are used to create beans. But if @Component was already there to create bean then what was the need of @Configuration (which use @Bean) to create bean. Please help in understand this and in which scenario we need to use the annotation.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose if you need to configure any third party class (like JdbcTemplate, Sendrgrid etc...) as spring bean then you should go with @Configuration annotation.
and your business related classes as spring bean then you should go with @Component annotation.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Check this link :

[Difference between @Component, @Service, @Controller, and @Repository in Spring](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2017/11/difference-between-component-service.html)

Comment: I am exactly looking for why the Configuration annotation came into picture if Component already exists , Not the difference exactly